# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute during form implemetntaion

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am getting this error when I run my Project and I tried all the fixes online but it did not work.

> Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute during form implementation

I am pasting the code below

Do I have to create a table in my database or how do I fix this?

I am trying to read the values entered from the form to another jsp page using spring mvc but without using annotations. And while doing so I am getting this error: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute My Controller Class code is as follows:

User.java

```java
    package User;

    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.Table;

    @Entity
    @Table 
    public class User {
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
     private Integer id;
     private String name;
     private Integer age;
     private String gender;
     private String email;
     private String city;
    
    

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
     
    

    }
```

UserController.java

```java
    package Controller;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
    import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

    import User.User;

    @Controller
    public class UserController {
    
    @Autowired
    
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String greetingForm(Model model) {
        
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return "greeting";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/greeting")
    public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute User user , Model model) {
        
        
        User newUser = new User();
        
        newUser.setName(user.getName());
        newUser.setAge(user.getAge());
        newUser.setGender(user.getGender());
        newUser.setEmail(user.getEmail());
        newUser.setCity(user.getCity());
        userRepository.save(user);
        
        return "result";
    }
    @GetMapping("/all")
    public String getMeassage(Model model ) {
        Iterable<User> users = userRepository.findAll();
        
        model.addAttribute("users", users);
        return "all";
    }
    
    }
```

greeting.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Form Submission</title>
<link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

    <br><br>
<h2 style="color:green">Form</h2>
    <br><br>

    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="#" th:action="@{/greeting}" th:object="${user}" modelAttribute="user" method="post">

        <div class="form-group" style="width:300px">
            <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                
                <input type="text"  th:field="*{name}" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" style="width:300px">
            <label for="age" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Age</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" th:field="*{age}" class="form-control" id="age" placeholder="Enter age">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" style="width:300px">
            <label for="gender" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Gender</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" th:field="*{gender}" class="form-control" id="gender" placeholder="Enter gender(M or F)">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" style="width:300px">
            <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" th:field="*{email}" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" style="width:300px">
            <label for="city" class="col-sm-2 control-label">City</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" th:field="*{city}" class="form-control" id="city" placeholder="Enter city">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn">Submit</button>
                <input type="reset" class="btn btn-warning" value="Reset" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: On which screen do you get the error?

Comment: when running the application

Comment: That is hardly an answer to my question. Which screen I was asking for, the form or the one after that or ...

Comment: The error comes up on the Form and the controller

Comment: It is either the form or the controller. Also **which** screen the first one or after the post or ...